# Yield inside synchronized block? Lock release after calling yield()?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I am creating a multiple threads and calling `yield()` inside it.

> The java.lang.Thread.yield() method causes the currently executing thread object to temporarily pause and allow other threads to execute.

Will It be possible for other threads to execute which also want to go inside synchronized block?

```
synchronized(this.lock)
{
 //calling yield here.

}
```

thanks.

Comment: Don't indent text blocks as the site formatter will treat it as code and make it un-readable. I tried to fix this but you "un-fixed" it. I will fix it one more time, but please don't change it back.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, Yield() only gives up the remaining time slice on the CPU and steps back in the queue. It doesn't release any synchronized objects.

Comment: +1 in short, it's a very bad idea. Use `this.lock.wait(1);` instead.

Answer (score 4):

`yield` does not take or release locks, it simply pauses the current thread execution. So yielding in the `synchronized` block will not let the current thread to release lock and let the other methods to enter the `synchronized` block. `wait/notify` method should be used to release the lock.

From [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.3)

> Thread.sleep causes the currently executing thread to sleep
>   (temporarily cease execution) for the specified duration, subject to
>   the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers. The thread
>   does not lose ownership of any monitors, and resumption of execution
>   will depend on scheduling and the availability of processors on which
>   to execute the thread.
>
> **It is important to note that neither Thread.sleep nor Thread.yield have any synchronization semantics**. In particular, the compiler does
>   not have to flush writes cached in registers out to shared memory
>   before a call to Thread.sleep or Thread.yield, nor does the compiler
>   have to reload values cached in registers after a call to Thread.sleep
>   or Thread.yield.

Answer (score 0):

`yield` allows a context switch to other threads, so this thread will not consume the entire CPU usage of the process. The thread still holds the lock. It is the developer responsibility to take care of deadlocks.